# Is there a performance gain if you don't use new in front of RegExp() vs. simply RegExp()?

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I want to replace all occurrences of a substring in a string.
Will there be any difference between the following two examples?

```
var str='A horse walks into a bar and the bartender asks "Hey, why the long face?".';

str.replace(new RegExp('bar','g'),'restaurant');
// versus
str.replace(RegExp('bar','g'),'restaurant');
```

**Note:**
This is a simplified example and unlike the above, I *need* to use RegExp instead of literal regular expression in order to concatenate the string.

Comment: When you measured it (by placing each in a loop that repeats its operation enough times to get a reasonable timing measurement), which took longer?

Comment: Yeah, I'm on my phone and I can't do a JSPerf now.

Comment: Plus, I'm looking for a reason besides the empirical data JSPerf would provide.

Answer (score 1):

Read the spec on what the [`RegExp`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.4.8) function does:

> **[15.10.3 The RegExp Constructor Called as a Function](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.3)**
>
> If pattern is an object R whose [[Class]] internal property is
>   "RegExp" and flags is undefined, then return R unchanged. *Otherwise
>   call the standard built-in RegExp constructor (15.10.4.1)* as if by the
>   expression new RegExp( pattern, flags) and return the object
>   constructed by that constructor.
>
> **[15.10.4 The RegExp Constructor](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.4)**
>
> When RegExp is called as part of a new expression, it is a
>   constructor: it initialises the newly created object.
>
> If pattern is an object R whose [[Class]] internal property is
>   "RegExp" and flags is undefined, then let P be the pattern used to
>   construct R and let F be the flags used to construct R. If pattern is
>   an object R whose [[Class]] internal property is "RegExp" and flags is
>   not undefined, then throw a TypeError exception. Otherwise, let P be
>   the empty String if pattern is undefined and ToString(pattern)
>   otherwise, and let F be the empty String if flags is undefined and
>   ToString(flags) otherwise.
>
> […and build a regex from the pattern]

So there is actually no difference. Without `new` it might be slower because it needs to check the type of `R`, with `new` it might be slower because there is an extra new-expression instead of a simple function call.

I'd guess even with an actual performance measure of an example you will not notice a difference.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm unsure of the internals of the RegEx function effectively if the function calls `this` it will use the global object rather than the new item.

Performance wise it will be the same, however if you are using several regex's they could conflict with each other since it would replace any varibles on the global object.

Both calls are not the preferred way instead the syntax is :
`str.replace(/bar/g,'restaurant');`

in the case of the example
and the following will also work:

```
var myRegex = /bar/g;
str.replace(myRegex,'restaurant');
```

Comment: +1 as the literal // is the fastest but I would not say the constructor call is depreciated, its the way to go if the pattern is a variable

Comment: Yeah 'deprecated' probally isnt the right word. "Non-prefered" ?

Comment: Thanks, but I wrote in the note that literals won't work for this instance.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote it really encourages us to help you. perhaps you could provide us with an example of what you are trying to achieve rather than adding notes after the fact.